# Can I believe in Allah without being muslim?

Tags: allah, five-pillars

I believe in Allah, the prophet Muhammad and the five pillars but, I don't think I'm ready to covert just yet. I'm confused and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

your question is contradict each other, if you already believe in Allah and prophet Muhammad then you already a muslim. sahadah don't have meaning if just spoken by mouth, what in heart that matter. Allah know clearly everything in this world, even it's something hidden in the heart.

Answer (score -1):

### In the name of God, the Beneficent, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to God, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever God guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but God, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**YOUR QUESTION:** Can I believe in Allah without being a Muslim?

**ANSWER:** in brief, no. Because, that would mean, you want to be a rejector of Truth which entails disbelief and if you have done disbelief, all your work will be in vain unless you come back to Islam by declaring the shahada and start doing righteous good deeds. So, you are a disbeliever if you don't want to be a Muslim.

God Says:

> "O People of the Scripture, do not commit excess in your religion or say about God except the truth. The Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, was but a messenger of God and His word which He directed to Mary and a soul [created at a command] from Him. So believe in God and His messengers. And do not say, "Three"; desist - it is better for you. Indeed, God is but one God. Exalted is He above having a son. To Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. And sufficient is God as Disposer of affairs." [[**The Women, 4:171**](https://quran.com/4/171)]

Don't you want to be saved from Hell? If you do want, then you got to recite shahada and start doing good deeds in order to be saved from Hell and also, put hope in God. Don't you know what God Says in Family of Imran? God Says:

> "And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers." [[**Family of Imran, 3:85**](https://quran.com/3/85)]

Which clearly means, that God will not accept what you are doing in case you have heard clearly the message of Islam which came upon you. So, you must believe in God and in whatever He tells you, God Almighty Says:

> "O you who have believed, believe in God and His Messenger and the Book that He sent down upon His Messenger and the Scripture which He sent down before. And whoever disbelieves in God, His angels, His books, His messengers, and the Last Day has certainly gone far astray" [[**The Women, 4:136**](https://quran.com/4/136)]

If you want to remain non Muslim, then you can be non Muslim, because God Says:

> And say, "The truth is from your Lord, so whoever wills - let him believe; and whoever wills - let him disbelieve." Indeed, We have prepared for the wrongdoers a fire whose walls will surround them. And if they call for relief, they will be relieved with water like murky oil, which scalds [their] faces. Wretched is the drink, and evil is the resting place" [[**The Cave, 18:29**](https://quran.com/18/29)]

If you think you aren't ready to convert to Islam, please study Islam well, know that Islam is the only true religion which God has Decreed upon us.

**We ask God to guide us to the Straight Path and to make us all people of Paradise. May God send blessings and peace upon His slave and Messenger Muhammad and upon his family and companions.**

---

**References:**

- [**Response to a stubborn disbeliever**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/4028/response-to-a-stubborn-disbeliever)
- [**How To Become a Muslim ?**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/11819/how-to-become-a-muslim)
- [**If things are decreed, then how can a person be called to account for them?**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/96978/if-things-are-decreed-then-how-can-a-person-be-called-to-account-for-them)

Comment: Seriously? Why down vote? Haven’t I told the truth?

Comment: I don‘t understand that down vote either.  Our history records the Prophet‘s (a.s.) uncle, Abu Talib, as  a kafir because the Prophet (a.s.) said the he didn‘t hear Abu Talib utter the shahadatain on his death bed. Yes, the shahada is “merely” the verbalization of one‘s mental state, BUT THAT VERBALIZATION NEEDS TO BE MADE. That is a step that must be taken to put someone on the path of Salvation, AND THAT‘S WHAT MAKES BELIEF VALUABLE - IT IS AN INDISPENSIBLE STEP TOWARDS SALVATION.